# which tables are affected by the Catalog URL Rewrites index in Magento?

Tags: indexing, magento

Pretty straightforward question, which tables are affected by the Catalog URL Rewrites index in Magento?

Each time I run this index it takes a long time to run and the admin status for the index gets stuck on PROCESSING.

I have tried to find lock tables with SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST and have TRUNCATED core_url_rewrite and now I am waiting for the rebuild to run again, while I listen for error in system.log.

It would be nice to know exactly which tables are used and if it is just core_url_rewrite and  catalogsearch_fulltext, which I have also truncated....

Just found these files:

magento/var/locks/index_process_1.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_2.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_3.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_4.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_5.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_6.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_7.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_8.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_9.lock 
magento/var/locks/index_process_10.lock

They seem to match times when I tried to run the index, but do they stop the index creation like a mysql lock file would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about what the process does, it's about how it does it. It will load up products one by one and do processing. Try to run

`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`

in your magento/shell directory. With a max_execution time set to zero and enough memory, it will eventually finish.

As long as the lock file is there, no other reindex process can start. The question about tables is a little more complex, try to turn mysql general log and watch for updates. The time spent in MySQL is not a big concern, instantiating product objects is both slow and leaky. Make sure you have [this patch](http://blog.ewtechnologies.com/magento-2/magento-memory-leak-1-4-1-1/).

Comment: thanks for your message, I know about the indexer.php with the reindex flag, but I am trying to get a deeper understanding.  Can you answer the original question?  "which tables are affected by the Catalog URL Rewrites index in Magento?"  or the sub question: "do .lock files stop the index creation like a mysql lock file would do?"